# jQuery UI Dialog in Tabs Using

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I use jQuery UI Tabs. Tabs in the dialog with the windows opened, but the UI plug-in does not work properly.

The tabs need to be side by side. Unfortunately we could not get the result.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post full code or a jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1):

Your code as you've posted in comments works, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pwvJu/).  It seems most likely that you're having a CSS issue, check the following things:

- If you upgraded jQuery UI, make sure you updated the CSS, it changes each release as well
- If you have additional CSS, see which style rule is interfering with an inspector like Firebug or Chrome, some additional selector match may be applying some unwanted styling here.

Comment: jQuery UI is up to date. But, must CSS element style changing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `tabs()` to initialize the widget:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

If you have done that, then the only thing I can think of is there is problem with putting widgets in other widgets.

Comment: Tabs giving permission. However, in the tabs dialog is not working:) the UI does not work in Dialog.

Comment: Javascript source: http://pastebin.com/5HgFPGgD

Comment: Html source: http://pastebin.com/Dw7eAD6B

Comment: Preview Image: http://i52.tinypic.com/k32hdy.png

Comment: Have you tried initializing the tabs first and then the dialog?

Comment: Yes, i tried. However, it did not work. Already before the tabs, then the dialog.

Answer (score -1):

I also think it's a CSS issue, you are starting a second div ID without closing the first one. Did you mean to nest both tab groups? If so the other thing that can make them not stay in a line side by side, is if their container div is not large enough or has padding interfering with the tabs.